# install drops to a (initramfs) prompts/busybox 16.04

Tags: boot, dual-boot, live-usb

I created a USB boot of Ubuntu 16.04 , pop it in and see things going okay for a while.. but then after a minute of booting I get a prompt I've never seen before..

the drive is a brand new sandisk usb 3.0 16GB

any idea?? is the bios preventing me from dual booting?  I checked and secureBoot is off.

[image]

Comment: You may have two problems. Boot with the `nomodeset` option, and unplug all USB devices. Don't try and run long-term on a USB flash drive. Make sure write-protect is off.

Comment: thanks @heynnema , I am googling how .. this is a brand new install so not sure

Comment: Ah, you created an install USB flash drive. Then you may need to use `nomodeset` and/or your USB flash build didn't go right, or your USB flash is defective or needs to be reformatted before use.

Comment: i ran the check.. after figuring out how to get into the advanced menu.. indeed it found 1 file had an error... repressing the stick now with https://unetbootin.github.io/

Comment: i redid the whole process, only to get an error found again.. this USB key is brand new but maybe I should return it and get a different brand.. hearing bad things about sandisk

Comment: The most reliable method is to burn the .iso file to a DVD. Building USB sticks can be tricky. Did you MD5SUM the .iso download to make sure that you got a good download?

Comment: @heynnema I'm in a foreign country.. and this laptop has no optical drive.. but I redid everything without UNetbootin and it WORKED

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wiped the thumbdrive 1-2 times , UNetbootin failed to even boot so I threw that out.. just did the plain old instructions for making a bootable drive in OS X..

If you get an error for 1 file, in the advanced menu check up.. try to install anyway.. that's what I did and everything loaded up fine.  Weird.